# iPad 3 crash on app launch with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, storyboard, ipad-3

I'm checking my app with iPad its working fine, the flow goes well. When I try with the iPad 3, It crashes with the following log:

```
 CrashReporter Key:   793204a942c8c4835c8ee40189ce37008d86e70c
 Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
 Process:         Jansirani [696]
 Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/3C74B74A-7D41-4A61-9EF5-F6E92252612D/Jansirani.app/Jansirani
 Identifier:      Jansirani
 Version:         ??? (???)
 Code Type:       ARM (Native)
 Parent Process:  launchd [1]

 Date/Time:       2013-05-29 08:43:23.546 -0700
 OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
 Report Version:  104

 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
 Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd2006882
 Crashed Thread:  0

 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0 Crashed:
 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x35a735b0 objc_msgSend + 16
 1   UIKit                             0x39307e14 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 80
 2   Jansirani                         0x000cea2e 0xcb000 + 14894
 3   Jansirani                         0x000d33be 0xcb000 + 33726
 4   UIKit                             0x39308ab6 -[UIViewAnimationState      sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 154
 5   UIKit                             0x3937d8d2 -[UIViewAnimationState      animationDidStop:finished:] + 46
    QuartzCore                        0x35619bd4 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 204
 7   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a91c4b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
 8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a9211b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 220
 9   CoreFoundation                    0x38624f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
 10  CoreFoundation                    0x38597eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
 11  CoreFoundation                    0x38597d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
 12  GraphicsServices                  0x3802a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
 13  UIKit                             0x393472fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
 14  Jansirani                         0x000cc4be 0xcb000 + 5310
 15  Jansirani                         0x000cc3dc 0xcb000 + 5084

 Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
 Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4d648 kevent64 + 24
 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a923974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a923654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

 Thread 2 name:  WebThread
 Thread 2:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4ceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4d048 mach_msg + 36
 2   CoreFoundation                    0x38626040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
 3   CoreFoundation                    0x38624d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
 4   CoreFoundation                    0x38597eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
 5   CoreFoundation                    0x38597d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
 6   WebCore                           0x35c07a70 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
 7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce730e _pthread_start + 306
 8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce71d4 thread_start + 4

 Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
 Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4ceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4d048 mach_msg + 36
 2   CoreFoundation                    0x38626040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
 3   CoreFoundation                    0x38624d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
 4   CoreFoundation                    0x38597eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
 5   CoreFoundation                    0x38597d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
 6   Foundation                        0x34f30bc8 +[NSURLConnection(Loader)      _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
 7   Foundation                        0x34fb4678 __NSThread__main__ + 968
 8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce730e _pthread_start + 306
 9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce71d4 thread_start + 4

 Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
 Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c5d594 __select + 20
 1   CoreFoundation                    0x3862a1f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce730e _pthread_start + 306
 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce71d4 thread_start + 4

 Thread 5 name:  AQClient
 Thread 5:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4ceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c4d048 mach_msg + 36
 2   CoreFoundation                    0x38626040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
 3   CoreFoundation                    0x38624d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
 4   CoreFoundation                    0x38597eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
 5   CoreFoundation                    0x38597d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
 6   AudioToolbox                      0x374f45b6 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 134
 7   AudioToolbox                      0x374d58a2 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
 8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce730e _pthread_start + 306
 9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37ce71d4 thread_start + 4

 Thread 6:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c5dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdccf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdca12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdc8a0 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 7:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c5dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdccf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdca12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdc8a0 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 8:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33c5dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdccf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdca12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x37cdc8a0 start_wqthread + 4

 Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x20081ce0    r1: 0x36c69a9a      r2: 0x3ca887e8      r3: 0x000002ae
r4: 0xd200687a    r5: 0x20081ce0      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fd34dac
r8: 0x1f59a7d0    r9: 0x0db1a6a6     r10: 0x20086b60     r11: 0x00000054
ip: 0x3c9ead64    sp: 0x2fd34d88      lr: 0x39307e19      pc: 0x35a735b0
   cpsr: 0x00000030

 Binary Images:xcb000 -    0xfdfff +Jansirani armv7  <dd6e16a91de839c4a35d8a9614df0bed> /var/mobile/Applications/3C74B74A-7D41-4A61-9EF5-F6E92252612D
```

The app which works fine with iPad 1,iphone. Only prob with ipad3. Please help me to resolve.

Comment: You have a dangling `UIImageView` pointer. First symbolicate the crash log, then post the code for the function corresponding to the third frame in stack trace: `2   Jansirani                         0x000cea2e 0xcb000 + 14894`.

Comment: im not getting clearly,can you please explain what exactly you mean.

Comment: What is symbolication: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html How to symbolicate stack trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports . If you have pointer to some address, and the underlying object stored in that location is destroyed, and then if you try and dereference (access) that pointer, you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception (there are other causes for this exception, but I think this is what's going on here). Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your log, you're trying to add an image that doesn't exist.

Check if you have an @2x version of the image (for retina)

i.e

myImage.png is for iPad 1, iPad 2

myImage@2x.png is for iPad 3.

Comment: You don't *need* a `@2x` version of the image. Even if the image didn't exist in the target, `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` would return `nil` and `-[UIImageView setImage:]` would simply be no-op. It wouldn't crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Mar0ux im not getting clearly,can you please explain what exactly you mean.